# About .JSONDecodeError, don't know what cause and how to fix it

Tags: python, pandas

trying to connect my price comparison code to `pandas`, but I got the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

the code is like:

```
keyword = str(input('找什麼? '))
pages = 10
parse_word = urllib.parse.quote(keyword)
for page in list(range(1, pages)):
    response = requests.get('https://ecshweb.pchome.com.tw/search/v3.3/all/results?q=' + parse_word + '&page=' + str(page) + '&sort=rnk/dc')
    raw_data = response.content.decode(encoding='utf-8')
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    try:
        myData = []
        for product in data['prods']:
            product_name = product['name']
            prod_id = product['Id']
            prod_price = product['price']
            link = 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/' + prod_id
            myData.append({
                "名稱":product_name,
                "價格":prod_price,
                "網址":link
            })
            today = str(datetime.date.today())
            fileName = today + '_' + keyword + '_Pchome.json'
            try:
                with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    json.dump(myData, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, skipkeys=True)        
            except Exception as err:
               print(str(err))
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))
print('完成!') 
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
#print(df)
print('='*150)
print(df.nsmallest(10, '價格'))
print('='*150)
```

and here is the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\Desktop\Python\Autoshop\pchome.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads    
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode    
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

wondering how to fix it

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Is it `data = json.loads(raw_data)`? Have you looked at the value of `raw_data` before attempting to decode it as JSON? It may contain a clue to the problem.

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 0):

You should observe `row_data`, maybe the content in it doesn't conform to JSON format.

For example:

```
text = """{"str1": 'str2'}""" 
json.loads(text)
```

and will show

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
```